# ¿Cómo validar fecha completa con javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

Estimados tengo un problema al validar fecha inicio y fecha término
lo que ocurre es que la validación funciona por día es decir si tengo una fecha por ejemplo fecha inicio 2019-02-13 fecha término 2019-04-01 , como podrán ver las fechas están correctas pero la función que uso valida el día , es decir como el día de la fecha de inicio es mayor al día de la fecha de término la función me muestra la alerta de fecha inicio no puede ser mayor a la fecha de término pero en realidad las fechas están bien.

Acá dejo la función `javascript`.

```
function ConvertirStringToDate(fechaString)
{
    var fechas = fechaString.split('/');
    if (fechas.length != 3)
        fecha = fechaString.split('-');
    var tipoDate = new Date(fechas[2], fechas[1], fechas[0]);
    return tipoDate;
}

function ValidarFiltroDeFechas(stringFechaDesde, stringFechaHasta) {
    stringFechaDesde=document.getElementById(stringFechaDesde).value;
    stringFechaHasta=document.getElementById(stringFechaHasta).value;
    Validador = { Estado: true, Mensaje: '' };
    if (stringFechaDesde === "" && stringFechaHasta === "") {
        swal({
            title: "Fechas Vacías!",
            text: "Por favor ingresar fechas de Inicio y Término",
            icon: "warning"
        });
    }

    if (stringFechaDesde === "") {
        swal({
              title: "Fecha Inicio es obligatoria!",
              text: "Por favor ingresar fecha de Inicio",
              icon: "warning"
            });
    }

    if (stringFechaHasta === "") {
        swal({
              title: "Fecha Término es obligatoria!",
              text: "Por favor ingresar fecha de Término",
              icon: "warning"
            });
    }

    var dateDesde = ConvertirStringToDate(stringFechaDesde);
    var dateHasta = ConvertirStringToDate(stringFechaHasta);

    if (dateDesde > dateHasta) {
        swal({
              title: "Fecha Incorrectas!",
              text: "Fecha Inicio no puede ser mayor a Fecha Término",
              icon: "warning"
            });
    }
}
```

Acá los input donde se ingresan las fechas stos tienen una funciòn de `jquery datepicker` que es la que muestra el calendario.

```
<b>Fecha Despegue:</b><input type="text"  class="form-control-static" name="txtfechadespegue" id="fechaDespegueAjax"   required>

<b>Fecha Arribo:</b><input type="text"   class="form-control-static" name="txtfechaarribo" id="fechaArriboAjax" required>
```

Acá dejo imagen del error, si se fijan, solo el día de la fecha de inicio es mayor al día de la fecha de término pero en realidad las fechas están bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Primero**: no has colocado el codigo de la funcion `ConvertirStringToDate` por lo que no sabemos como estas conviertiendo la cadena a fecha. **Segundo**: Si estas usando jQuery por que no lo utilizas para obtener los valores de los input. **Tercero**: si ya estas usando el datepicker, no obtengas la cadena del input para luego convertirla a una fecha, porque puedes obtener el objeto Date asi: `$("#id_elemento").datepicker('getDate');`

Comment: A perdon ahora ya ingrese la función ConvertirStringToDate

Comment: Estoy convirtiendo bien la cadena a fecha con la función?

Comment: Tu dices que no debería usar la función ConvertirStringToDate? solo usar $("#id_elemento").datepicker('getDate'); ? esta linea convierte a fecha?

Comment: Intenta utilizando `.datepicker('getDate')` y recuerda que `#id_elemento` donde id_elemento es el id de tu input.  
Creo que deberias de crear la fecha de esta forma: `new Date(fechas[0], fechas[1], fechas[2]);` Si miras la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date), hace referencia que primero se pasa el año, el mes y el dia.

Comment: solo tienes que comparar los dates `console.log(dateDesde .getTime() >= dateHasta .getTime())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dice @Orlando De La Rosa en el comentario, para crear el date los parámetros deben ir en el órden (año, mes, día) así: `new Date(fechas[0], fechas[1], fechas[2]);`

Es importante notar también que los meses en Js empiezan con el 0, es decir Enero es el mes 0 y Diciembre el mes 11, por lo que al segundo parámetro normalmente se le resta 1.

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacer funcionar el código, le tuve que hacer unas modificaciones para que funcione en el editor de código de Stackoverflow.

un detalle importante, dentro de la función `ConvertirStringToDate` fijate que primero definís la variable `fechas` y debajo del if usas `fecha` sin `s` eso daba un error al querer convertir la fecha.

```js
document.getElementById("fechaDespegueAjax").value = "2019-05-03"
document.getElementById("fechaArriboAjax").value = "2019-05-02"

function ConvertirStringToDate(fechaString)
{
    var fechas = fechaString.split('/');
    if (fechas.length != 3)
        fechas = fechaString.split('-');
    var tipoDate = new Date(parseInt(fechas[0]), parseInt(fechas[1]) - 1, parseInt(fechas[2]));
    return tipoDate;
}

function ValidarFiltroDeFechas() {

    let stringFechaDesde=document.getElementById("fechaDespegueAjax").value;
    let stringFechaHasta=document.getElementById("fechaArriboAjax").value;
    
    Validador = { Estado: true, Mensaje: '' };
    if (stringFechaDesde === "" && stringFechaHasta === "") {
        return alert("Fechas Vacías!");
    }

    if (stringFechaDesde === "") {
        return alert( "Por favor ingresar fecha de Inicio");
    }

    if (stringFechaHasta === "") {
        return alert("Por favor ingresar fecha de Término");
    }

    var dateDesde = ConvertirStringToDate(stringFechaDesde);
    var dateHasta = ConvertirStringToDate(stringFechaHasta);
    if (dateDesde > dateHasta) {
        return alert("Fecha Inicio no puede ser mayor a Fecha Término");
    }
    
    alert("fecha de inicio es menor o son iguales!")
}
```

```html
<b>Fecha Despegue:</b><input type="text"  class="form-control-static" name="txtfechadespegue" id="fechaDespegueAjax"   required>

<b>Fecha Arribo:</b><input type="text"   class="form-control-static" name="txtfechaarribo" id="fechaArriboAjax" required>

<button onClick="ValidarFiltroDeFechas()">validar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho